# F4 search add into smart table ui5

Tags: sapui5

I have tried to configure <kbd>F4</kbd> search filed into smart table in UI5. I could't achieve it.

How do I configure <kbd>F4</kbd> search (smart field) in smart table SAP UI5

Answer (score 0):

Actually F4 works in SmartFilterBar fields, check the sample [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.ui.comp.sample.smartfilterbar/preview).
The Fiori word for F4 SearchHelp (SHLP) is: [Value Help](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/value-help-dialog/)

You can provide a descriptor called annotation.xml in your UI to configure Value Helps. You can tell for each Entity Property an EntitySet, a collection to browse from when you want to select values.

In manifest.json you can assign annotation to model and tell the location of the annotation file:

```
"mainService": {
  "uri": <yourServiceUri>,
  "type": "OData",
  "settings": {
    "odataVersion": "2.0",
    "localUri": "localService/metadata.xml",
    "annotations": [
      "annotation0"
    ]
  }
},
"annotation0": {
  "type": "ODataAnnotation",
  "uri": "./annotation0.xml"
}
```

Comment: This is for smart filter bars and as of UI5 version 1.6 this does not add search help to smart table filter inputs